# Extract time from datetime for comparison in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a DataFrame

```
customer_number   purchase_time         quantity
14                2007-03-01 07:06:00   10
20                2007-03-12 13:05:00   13
```

I tried to find the total quantity bought in the morning and afternoon. I converted `purchase_time` into datetime

```
df['purchase_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['purchase_time'])
# Baskets bought in morning.
df[df['purchase_time'] < '12:00:00']
```

However, the result is original dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Boolean array in a groupby

```
df.groupby(df.purchase_time.dt.hour < 12).sum().rename(
    {True: 'Morning', False: 'Afternoon'})

               customer_number  quantity
purchase_time                           
Afternoon                   20        13
Morning                     14        10
```

Comment: I liked this but I would either include customer_number in groupby or not at all, right?

Answer (score 10):

You can

```
df[df['purchase_time'].dt.time < pd.to_datetime('12:00:00').time()]
Out[152]: 
   customer_number       purchase_time  quantity
0               14 2007-03-01 07:06:00        10
```

Comment: I got an error when trying combined condition `df[df['purchase_time'].dt.time > pd.to_datetime('12:00:00').time() & df['purchase_time'] < pd.to_datetime('18:00:00').time()`. error message : `unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'`

Comment: (df['purchase_time'].dt.time > pd.to_datetime('12:00:00').time()) &( df['purchase_time'] < pd.to_datetime('18:00:00').time()) try it @Homesand

Answer (score 6):

You may not require a conversion here, just compare the times lexicographically -

```
df[df['purchase_time'].str.split().str[1] < '12:00:00']

   customer_number        purchase_time  quantity
0               14  2007-03-01 07:06:00        10
```

Although, for an extra layer of security, I'd recommend converting to `timedelta` and comparing - these comparisons still work with strings (pandas is miraculous that way) -

```
df[pd.to_timedelta(
       df['purchase_time'].str.split().str[1], errors='coerce'
) < '12:00:00']

   customer_number        purchase_time  quantity
0               14  2007-03-01 07:06:00        10
```

Comment: Thank you. what is the purpose of converting into datatime in pandas, while we can proceed the dataset with object type? What if I want to find the baskets bought in March, I can follow your instruction and do it with split method, right?

Comment: @Homesand In that case, converting to datetime would be very useful. You can do `pd.to_datetime(df['purchase_time']).dt.month == 3`, quite easily.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `purchase_time` is of `datetime` dtype:

```
In [88]: df.query("purchase_time.dt.hour < 12 and purchase_time.dt.month in [3,6]")
Out[88]:
   customer_number       purchase_time  quantity
0               14 2007-03-01 07:06:00        10
```

Comment: I had no idea you could accessors in query/eval strings.

Comment: @piRSquared, frankly speaking i'm not sure whether it's a new feature or not... But if something like this isn't working we can try to use `engine='python'` - this will work in most of the cases...